# Median and IQR "NA"

Tags: r

```
median(classifyforblack$Survival.months[classifyforblack$newcolumn == 'GU'])
[1] NA
```

> Warning message:
> In mean.default(sort(x, partial = half + 0L:1L)[half + 0L:1L]) :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I need to calculate median survival months when the value is GU but it give this error. I think that is because some values in survival months are"unknown" how to overcome that?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Please give us some context to your question. Take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints. It's a good start to give some data, make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and give an example of your desired output.

Comment: We need to see your data, to give you an answer. Most likely `Survival.months` doesn't contain numeric values. Besides "unknown" what are the other values auf `Survival.months`?

Comment: As per the error message `Survival.months` is  "not numeric or logical".

Comment: My best guess: (1) Replace "unknown" by `NA`. (2) Convert `Survival.months` into a numeric vector using `as.double` or `as.integer`. (3) Use the `na.rm = TRUE` argument of `mean()`.